# Accessing children of loaded swf in Flex Image component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

`enter code here`I am loading an external swf into an  component. It loads everything fine and I can see buttons working in the swf, I can add a movieclip to the  but I can't then access that movieclip (or don't know how), and it keeps telling me numChildren = null when I try to trace it out.

This is set up as a custom component like this:

```
<cynergy:imageZoom
    id="zoomComponent" 
            borderStyle="solid" 
            source="{_data.map.@url}"
            fadeDuration="1000" 
            bottom="0" left="0" top="0" right="0"
            zoomIncrement="{ options.zoomIncrement }"
            imageDoubleClickEnabled="{ options.imageDoubleClickEnabled }"
            mouseWheelEnabled="{ options.mouseWheelEnabled }"
            mouseFollow="{ options.mouseFollowEnabled }"  />


>



</cynergy>
```

Then in my imageZoom.mxml I have this code:

```
<Canvas
    visible="{ _source != null &amp;&amp; image.percentLoaded &lt; 100 }" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" 
    hideEffect="WipeDown" showEffect="WipeDown" width="210" height="30"
    borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="3" borderColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" backgroundAlpha=".5" cornerRadius="10" >

    <Label text="Loading... { Math.floor(image.percentLoaded) }%" fontSize="16" width="100%" textAlign="center">
        <filters>
            <flash.filters:DropShadowFilter color="0" alpha=".5" />
        </filters>
    </Label>

</Canvas>


<Image id="image" mask="{ maskCanvas }" source="{ _source }" mouseDown="image.startDrag()" visible="{ _source != null &amp;&amp; image.percentLoaded == 100 }"
    showEffect="{ fadeInEffect }" complete="imageComplete()" doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="onDoubleClick()" />
```

Can anyone tell me how I would access the children in the loaded movieclip?

I have tried

mycomponent.image.getChildAt(2) and it returns and error that the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your code can reference myComponent.image as you are doing it?  You may have issues with 'image' not able to be referenced in actionscript at all

Comment: yes, the mycomponent.image can be accessed through actionscript. I can even add things to it, I just don't know how to access those things now that I have added them.  It keeps producing numChildren= null.

Comment: I put a little more detail into the question, anyone have an idea as to what I might be doing wrong or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Was an easy answer:  myComponent.image.content

Also was calling it before it finished loading.